# Why does ngIf break the functionality of the components inside it? How should i handle this case?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angular-material

My goal is to have some button-placeholders for sections that have not been filled with information. The sections that are filled have a card appearance and feature an edit button which either activates editing (via froala, a rich text editor) or a wizard with form inputs.
My intention was to have the cards hidden when they are not filled or being edited and have the placeholder buttons just show the cards and then trigger the edit, which makes the froala pop up.
This is the code:

[a card component - breaking ngIf included]

```
        <div class="mat-card margin-bottom-16" *ngIf="!!this.project.description || editingProjectDescription">
            <div class="section-header">
                <div class="section-header-title">
                    <span>{{ 'SHARED.LABEL.DESCRIPTION' | translate }}</span>
                </div>
                <div class="section-actions" *ainPermission="{ name: 'ProjectEdit', params: project }">
                    <button *ngIf="!isLightProject" mat-icon-button (click)="editDescription()">
                        <mat-icon aria-label="edit">edit</mat-icon>
                    </button>
                    <button *ngIf="!isLightProject" mat-icon-button [popper]="popper2Content"
                        [popperShowOnStart]="false" [popperTrigger]="'hover'" [popperApplyClass]="'tooltip'"
                        [popperHideOnClickOutside]="true" [popperHideOnScroll]="true" [popperPlacement]="'right'">
                        <i class="material-icons info-color">info</i>
                    </button>
                    <popper-content class="tooltip-text" #popper2Content>
                        <span class="tooltip-text">{{ 'PROJECT.TOOLTIPS.DESCRIPTION' | translate }}</span>
                    </popper-content>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="description mat-typography mat-body-1">
                <ain-inline-froala-editor #inlineFroalaDescription [data]="inlineFroalaDescriptionConfig"
                    [add]="!this.project.description"></ain-inline-froala-editor>
            </div>
        </div>
```

[code from the component containing the card]

```
export class ProjectViewGeneralComponent implements OnInit, OnDestroy {

    project: Project;
    ...
    editingProjectDescription = false;
    editingProjectPlan = false;

    @ViewChild('inlineFroalaDescription', { static: true }) inlineFroalaDescription: InlineFroalaEditorComponent;
    @ViewChild('inlineFroalaProjectPlan', { static: true }) inlineFroalaProjectPlan: InlineFroalaEditorComponent;

    ...

    editDescription(): void {
        this.inlineFroalaDescription.show();
    }

    showDescription(): void {
        this.editingProjectDescription = true;
    }

    get inlineFroalaDescriptionConfig(): Object {
        return {
            action: ProjectActions.UpdateProjectDescription,
            mode: 'simpleExtended',
            extraConfig: {
                placeholderText: this.translate.instant('PROJECT.TEXT.DESCRIPTION_PLACEHOLDER')
            },
            storeName: 'project',
            value: this.project.description,
            required: true,
            requiredProp: {
                id: this.project.id,
                valueProperty: 'description'
            }
        };
    }

    ...
```

[the error] ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'show' of undefined
in the editDescription method, this line

```
this.inlineFroalaDescription.show();
```

Basically 'inlineFroalaDescription' ceases to exist.

Comment: You must define breaking.

Comment: @AluanHaddad i edited my question and added more info, check it out

Comment: So, the view children don't exist at certain times because `*ngIf` adds or removes components it doesn't hide or show them. There are two options, you can either check to make sure that the view children currently have a value before you use them or you can data bind to `[hidden]` instead of using `*ngIf`